# How to change the Craft 3 activation email?

Tags: craft3, users, emails

In my organization many of the employees believe the user activation email sent out by Craft is spam.  How do I change the email text and possibly add an image, like our company logo, to the email?

Answer (score 4):

Under Settings > Email there is a field called "HTML Email Template" which you can use to point to a single template that handles all of the system emails. It's not very obvious from the Craft UI, but you can use that single template as a routing mechanism for including per-email templates using the variable `emailKey` which is available in the template. Your routing template could look like this:

```
{# Craft has four predefined email keys:

    account_activation
    verify_new_email
    forgot_password
    test_email

... route to them here, or fallback to default
#}

{% include [
    '_emails/' ~ emailKey ?? null,
    '_emails/default'
] %}
```

You'd then have another template called `account_activation.twig` where you can go wild with whatever modifications you like. Each email also has a `link` variable available in the template to output the link to whatever it is.

Comment: This works great for HTML emails, but I noticed the plain text component of the email is still using the system messaging (easy to spot if using MailHog in development). Any idea how to target updating the text version also?

Comment: great question, let me know here if you find out a way!

Comment: For now I just ended up editing the text message in Utilities > System Messages, so they at least match up roughly with my custom HTML equivalents.